# Location of Error Page html file in config.xml inside IONIC project, to be used when offline/ no network connection, to show error message

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

We are working on an Ionic app for an enterprise product.
All of the data/content/web assets used in the project are loaded from remote location like S3.

In config.xml, the path to index.html can be like this for example

Due to this, we need to handle the ‘no network/ internet’ scenario.

config.xml has an option ‘ErrorUrl’ which should point to errorPage.html.

My question is,

In an IONIC project, where should this error html page reside & what should it’s path be in config.xml ???

Following are the links for reference that I have gone through but didn’t get any concrete answer,

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/config_ref/#preference
(Search for ErrorUrl property)

https://www.raymondcamden.com/2013/02/19/Some-examples-of-Android-PhoneGap-Config-Settings

Please help me with this !

Thanks in advance :slight_smile:

Answer (score 0):

With Ionic, you can use the [Network plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/network/) to handle the network connections errors.

**Install**

Run these commands in your Ionic project folder

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-network-information
npm install --save @ionic-native/network
```

**Set up**

You need to add the plugin to your app's module in the `app.module.ts` file :

```
import { Network } from '@ionic-native/network';

@NgModule({
  providers: [
    Network
  ]
})
```

**Use**

You can easily catch the network changes with these functions :

```
this.network.onDisconnect().subscribe(() => {
  //You will enter here everytime the connection is lost
})

this.network.Connect().subscribe(() => {
  //You will enter here everytime the connection is retrieved
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply @saperlipopette ! If you have read carefully then whole of my app's code is coming from remote server, including the starting point point of Ionic app, index.html. When user doesn't have the app, running and he opens it without internet connection, I want to show error message. Did you get it ? Please let me know how to use the "errorUrl" pref in config.xml to resolve this.

Comment: Oh sorry didn't get it. I thought you were loading the app after the index.html. According to the docs, the use of the ErrorUrl is the following : `<preference name="ErrorUrl" value="myErrorPage.html"/>`. The `myErrorPage.html` must be at the same level as the config.xml file

Comment: @AbhishekKanitkar were you able to get this resolved? I too have the same issue in Android